# How to wait for a script node to finish loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In javascript, I am inserting a `<script tag>` into an iframe like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var doc= iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

var jquery = document.createElement("script");
jquery.type = "text/javascript";
jquery.src   = "jquery-1.9.1.min.js";

var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = "blah.js";

doc.appendChild(jquery);
doc.appendChild(script);
```

However, there is jquery code in the `blah.js`, and sometimes this script fails because the jquery script didn't finish loading yet. Is there a way to wait until it finished loading?

Thanks.

Comment: `script.onready = function () { ... }` (or being a cool guy and using addEventListener/attachEvent) I suppose

Comment: do you mean `jquery.onready = function () { ... }` and then in the function, I load the `script` variable?

Comment: I tried this `jquery.onready = function() { alert(1); }` but the alert never happened.

Comment: actually, its `onload` not `onready`....

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use `script.onload = functionName;` with a fix for IE8. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437678/2227298 for the complete code.

Once jQuery is loaded, you can use [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript) with the success parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Add a callback at the end of the first script.

at the end of jquery.js:

```
if (window.jqueryLoaded)
    window.jqueryLoaded();
```

in your code:

```
// create the function that will be called once jquery finishes loading
function jqueryLoaded()
{
    doc.appendChild(blah);
}

// load jquery
doc.appendChild(jquery);
```

Alternative (not really recommended) way by using a timer if you can't modify the jquery.js file:

```
var checkjQuery = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (!window.jQuery)
        return;
    window.clearInterval(checkjQuery);

    window.jqueryLoaded();
}, 10);
```

Comment: Is there another way, I can't modify the `jquery-1.9.1.min.js"` file

Comment: edited the answer to show an approach with a timer instead.