# Delay callback until script is added to document?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the callback to not run until the script is actually appended to the document?

```
function addScript(filepath, callback){
    if (filepath) {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filepath);
        if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the ideal world, you could use the `onload` property of the `<script />` tag;

```
function addScript(filepath, callback){
    if (filepath) {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');

        fileref.onload = callback;

        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filepath);

        if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
}
```

However, [this doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845762/onload-handler-for-script-tag-in-internet-explorer), so mega-h4x are required;

```
  function addScript(filepath, callback) {
      if (filepath) {
          var fileref = document.createElement('script');
          var done = false;
          var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

          fileref.onload = fileref.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete")) {
                  done = true;

                  callback();

                  // Handle memory leak in IE
                  fileref.onload = fileref.onreadystatechange = null;
                  if (head && fileref.parentNode) {
                      head.removeChild(fileref);
                  }
              }
          };

          fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
          fileref.setAttribute("src", filepath);

          head.appendChild(fileref);
      }
  }
```

FWIW, your `if (typeof fileref != "undefined")` was redundant, as it will always evaluate to true, so you can just do `head.appendChild(fileref);` directly, as in my example.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
var myParticularCallback = function () {
    // do something neat ...
}

..... your code  

var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");

fileref.onload = myParticularCallback;

if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

 // after all has set, laod the script and wait for onload event:
fileref.setAttribute("src", filepath);
```

Comment: Really like the solution to use

fileref.onload = myParticularCallback

Answer (score 1):

This tiny script / css loader will do the job
https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/

```
LazyLoad.js('/foo.js', function () {
  alert('foo.js has been loaded');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way will be define some visible `callback()` function which will run in your dynamicly included script, at the end.

Comment: I cannot touch the dynamically included script.