# Append <script> tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to append `<script></script>` tag dynamically, using jQuery or pure JavaScript, with a callback function.

Please note two **important** things:

1) The  tag might includes more attributes then 'src' that should be included on the tag. e.g:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous" exclude="true"></script>
```

**There is no only url here**.

2) It should execute a **callback** function after the script has loaded.

> This is **not** duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743772/delay-callback-until-script-is-added-to-document) as I have no idea which attributes the
>   script contains.

Comment: So theres a thing called a search engine - https://www.google.ie/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=append%20items%20to%20the%20dom&oq=append%20items%20to%20the%20dom&aqs=chrome..69i57.4522j0j7

Comment: @Craicerjack Nice tool. None of the results there has callback functionality (after the script has loaded). Many answers show how to do so by getting url parameter, that's easy, but what about all the other attributes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay callback until script is added to document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743772/delay-callback-until-script-is-added-to-document)

Comment: It doesn't duplicate with these as I have no idea which attributes the script contains.

Comment: @Jacob Your question is quite specific but also vague. How do you find out what attributes? What have you tried? You could take the `addScript` function below and add an object with all of the attributes instead of just the source. Combine this with the duplicate comment above and what more do you need?

Comment: throwing something like `myBodyIsReady()` at the end of that script file or throwing the onload attribute into the script node would not do it for you? i cannot imagine any usecase for this. be more explicit.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1):

We can use append http://api.jquery.com/append

```
function addScript(source, callback) {
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.type = "text/javascript";
    tag.src = source;
    tag.onload = callback;
    $("body").append(tag);
};
```

Comment: This function doesn't consider the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the creation of an element, you could have a function like this. Then call it with the necessary attributes that you need. Append that to the `DOM` and then follow the comment regarding delaying the callback until the script has loaded.

```
function createElement(element, attributes, text) {
    // function to create an element with class and text if wanted.
    // attributes is an object of key value items. Key is the attribute, value is the value.
    var el = document.createElement(element);
    $.each(attributes, function(key, value) {
        el.setAttribute(key, value);
    });
    if (text) {
        var t = document.createTextNode(text);
        el.appendChild(t);
    }
    return el;
}
```

Which can be used like this:
`createElement("script", { "src": "your_src", "tag": "your_tag });`

Comment: Thank you for that. How can I get a list of attribute from the text? e.g: "<script src="..." attr1="..." attr2="..."></script>"

Comment: from what text?

Comment: @Jacob do you actually know how to javascript?

Comment: @GottZ Sure !!! The function in the answer gets 'attributes' parameter. But I get a plain text that looks like that: "<script src="..." attr1="..." attr2="..."></script>" I don't know what will be the parameters' names, so I can not use this function.

Comment: @Jacob The function in the answer is to create an element with a certain no of attributes. You have to pass in the attributes. How do you expect to create an element with attributes if you dont have those attributes?

Comment: @Craicerjack I can append the line of text that I get into the head and the script will be loaded considering all the needed attributes (I don't have to know their names) e.g: head.append('<script src="http://..." attr1="..." attr2="..."></script>"); --> This code will do fine but then I miss the loaded callback function.

Comment: upvoted since i think this answered the actual question quite well. due to jacobs comment here i just made my own little answer now.