# How to trigger a redraw using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am using *Twitter's* basic widget and have run into a problem: the page does not allocate enough vertical space when initially loading the widget. This often results in the widget overlapping the content below.

Although I could add a wrapper `div` around it within a minimum height, I am looking to trigger a redraw using a `callback`. I have been able to add a callback to the code described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798707/twitter-embedded-timeline-callback) and in appending an empty `div`, it does force a redraw which corrects the display issue.

Is there any other way to trigger a redraw without modifying the dom or making a smaller change than appending a div?

Comment: I think you are trying to over-engineer a fix for something that seems to be better handled in markup/CSS.

Comment: What you actually want is another layout pass. The browser won’t do that unless it’s needed. You could just fix the size of the container.

Comment: It seems you can fix this issue easily by proper CSS markup, look for parent elements with overflow:hidden with fixed heights or proper usage of [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for floated elements.