# What happened when a <script> tag is encountered within a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am just wondering when `<script src="http://...example.js"/>`  is encountered in an HTML file, what will happen? Is there some event handler or there will be something like a get request sent?

Comment: [I recommend reviewing the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-script-element).

Comment: Yes, there's a GET request. Regarding an event handler, do you mean something that is triggered when it's done loading? If so, most browsers have an `onload` event that can be bound.

Comment: Good question, everytime a script tag is encountered a unicorn is born, that's actually where they come from.

Comment: lol, I've also heard something about unicorn, like some interviewers ask what that unicorn in js book cover comes from. Can you explain it a bit, how does that relate to <script> tag?

Comment: There seems to be an onload event even for script tags.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845762/onload-handler-for-script-tag-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in HTML5 CR, in the section on the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element). In the example case, since neither the `defer` nor the `async` attribute is used, the browser will fetch (with a GET request) and execute the script before continuing the processing of the HTML document. The default handling is thus synchronous blocking behavior.

However, if you really use markup like `<script src="http://...example.js"/>` without an end tag `</script>`, the script is not fetched at all, except in the rare case where you serve the HTML document with an XML content type. The reason is that `<script src="http://...example.js"/>` is parsed as a start tag only, so all the rest is parsed as content of a `script` element, and when no end tag is parsed, the `script` element is not completed. So don’t try to use “self-closing” syntax; instead, write `<script src="http://...example.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the browser stops everything it's doing--stops rendering, stops the event loop, stops listening to or acting on input. This state is called "blocking." It then executes whatever is in the script block, or retrieves the script which is referenced in the `src` attribute via a GET request, then executes it when it arrives. After execution, the browser comes out of blocking and continues to parse the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, script sources aren't loaded asynchronously, which means execution will stop until it's loaded. As such, there's no need for an event that announces when it's done. Hopefully someone will correct me on this if I'm wrong.