# Explanation of event handler definition

Tags: javascript

I tried the code snippet given by Google for the use of the spreadsheet API in JavaScript from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). It works but I don't understand the following part.

```html
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
    onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
    onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

In particular, why the code is written that way instead of as follows:

```html
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
    onload="handleClientLoad()">
</script>
```

Comment: I'm frankly amazed it uses `onload` at all. It's not 1998 anymore, no one should be using `on...` handlers anymore.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: It's likely the most concise cross-browser/version snippet. If you wanted to use the DOM API to add the event handlers you would have to add some way to find the element (e.g. ID) and make sure that that doesn't collide with other elements. This is pretty much self contained and will "just work".

Comment: that seems unlikely, though, `(function blah(...) { ... })();` works in any browser with even the most basic JS support, and doesn't require any kind of `onload` monitoring of the script. It simply runs when parsing is complete. (you might very well be right, of course, but then someone at Google didn't realise onload was unnecessary)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: *"It simply runs when parsing is complete."* Uh? The `onload` handler runs when the code the script element is referring to was evaluated. That happens some time in the future.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Regardless of your preferences, inline JavaScript is still extremely common. Programming teachers and tutorials don't adopt modern techniques quickly, they keep teaching the same way they have for decades.

Comment: Assigning to `this.onload` inside the `onload=` attribute seems very weird. When the inline code finishes running, would it still execute a new `onload` handler?

Comment: I think this might be a workaround for IE < 10 not understanding `async`. There's some mention of that [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4845762/1048572), not all browsers support the `load` event on script tags (guess which one…). That's why they are listening on the `readystatechange` event as well, and when the script was loaded they call the `onload` handler. The handler overwrites itself with an empty function so that `handleClientLoad()` is not called twice.